# How to add icon Keyboard layout to System Tray

Tags: release-freya, keyboard, wingpanel, keyboard-layout

I have two languages are Vietnamese and English.
My Shortcut is Alt+Space for change language layout.
How can i add icon which language i'm using to System Tray?

Answer (score 2):

Keyboard indicator appears after add two or more layouts in keyboard settings.

[image: keyboard layout settings]

Comment: My System  Trai didn't sir

Comment: `sudo apt-get install indicator-keyboard` ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it works if you set English(US) at first (I don't know why, but English Intl. didn't work for me) and then some other language, the icon magically appears. I had the same issue with EN/PT.